# Binding to Code Behind will not work

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8

I have a button, which calls a method that populates a `List<string>` with paths to images. I am trying to update a Windows 8 app each time this method is called to show all of the images produced.
Currently it will not show anything, despite simply hardcoding the image path into the `List<string>`

My XAML code to display the images is  :

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=test}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

And in the Xaml.cs :

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : TestApp.Common.LayoutAwarePage
{

    public List<string> test = new List<string>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        test.Add("C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\image.jpg");
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong/needs to be changed here ? Thanks very much :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the DataContext of your MainPage. Put this on your MainPage xaml.

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

EDIT: You need to have a property on your code-behind, not a field:

```
public List<string> test {get; set;}
public MainPage()
{
    test = new List<string>();
    test.Add("C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\image.jpg");
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer...I have added this, and the image still does not appear :(

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors in your Output window? Are there at least items showing up in the ItemsControl now, but just no images?

Comment: Nothing is showing up, unfortunately. This is the error message produced from the Output window (many thanks for telling me to check this also, I didn't realise binding issues were output at all!)

Error: BindingExpression path error: 'test' property not found on 'TestApp.MainPage'. BindingExpression: Path='test' DataItem='TestApp.MainPage'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl' (Name='null'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'Object')

Comment: Oh...that's because you've got a public FIELD on your code behind...not a public PROPERTY. I'll edit my answer to make it clear.

Comment: I am now getting the error Error: Converter failed to convert value of type 'Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<String>' to type 'ImageSource'; BindingExpression: Path='' DataItem='Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<String>'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' (Name='null'); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource'). 


But at least the binding appears to work ! :)

Comment: Well I would suggest you post a separate question on SO for the latest issue. I have not done any Windows 8 programming, so I don't know what's changed regarding setting paths for images. As you're able to now see the items in your ItemsControl, I think your original question has been answered?

Comment: Your property should be of type BitmapImage not string